# Why my new Flutter project runs on kotlin and swift?

Tags: android-studio, flutter

My new project runs on kotlin and swift, but i want to run project on java and objective-c, i want to switch this setting. My version of Android Studio is 3.4.1. And I didn't chose kotlin and swift variation. How can i reach this goal.

Comment: When creating projects via Android Studio or IntelliJ, you have option to select which lang will be used for android/ios. But I suggest you to go with Swift. Android side doesn't matter much.

Comment: I'll change questions

Comment: launch `flutter create -h` command and search for `language` keyword

Answer (score 1):

Flutter switched the default languages to kotlin and swift but there is a command line switch -i or --ios-language and -a or --android-language

To update an existing project you should be able to delete the ios and android directories and run
flutter create -i objc -a java